# How do you display pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do you display pages from the database in Wordpress to show on the front end. I know how to display the posts but in this case I want the pages to be displayed. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: Pages display automatically, you just need to link to them.

Comment: im trying to create a custom theme

Comment: So your question is "how do you display the content of a page in a wordpress template?"

Comment: im creating a custom theme and need the code to display the page in wordpress rather than the posts.

Comment: So you want the homepage to be a static page instead of a list of posts?

Comment: Start by looking at a working theme.

Comment: a@PAD1 - Yes you're right

Comment: In the backend go to `settings>reading` and change the `Front page displays` option to `Static page` and then select the page you want to display from the `Front page` dropdown.

Comment: I need the code to insert into PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you're asking, but it seems like you're trying to figure out how to display the content of a page, in which case it's the same as displaying posts:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: i tried this one but it displays my posts instead of my pages

Comment: You need to add it to your page template and then assign that template to the page you're trying to display. Otherwise just add it to `page.php` if you're not planning on using a custom page template. Also, it may help you understand if you take a look at the code of an existing theme as @Sparky suggested.

Comment: You're quite welcome!